# RCPTT Maven Plugin procedures

Tags: java, eclipse, maven-plugin, eclipse-rcptt

***TL;DR***

I'm trying to create a simple RCPTT test and run it using the **rcptt-maven-plugin** but I'm unable to do so because my procedure declarations in contexts are not being found.

Is there a way to specify the contexts location or some other way to make them work in the maven plugin?

---

Hi

I have a RCPTT project with one test case and one context file declaring global procedures.
When I run the test from the **RCP Testing Tool IDE** it works just fine, but when I run it via the **rcptt-maven-plugin**, the test ends with an error stating the procedure was not found.

Content of context file with the procedure declaration:

```
Format-Version: 1.0
Context-Type: org.eclipse.rcptt.ctx.ecl
Element-Name: projectsList
Element-Type: context
Element-Version: 2.0
Id: _N9ok0BEVEeqDjsfnLlxoAg
Runtime-Version: 2.4.3.201909171500
Save-Time: 11/27/19 2:11 PM

------=_.ecl.context-718f04b4-ed39-33e3-af62-0995e4561998
Content-Type: text/ecl
Entry-Name: .ecl.context

proc createNewProject [val projectName] {
    get-view "Projects list" | get-tree | get-menu -path "New/Project..." | click
    with [get-window "New Project"] {
        with [get-tree] {
            select "Configuration Console" | double-click
            select "Configuration Console/New Project" | double-click
        }
        get-editbox -after [get-label "Project name:"] | set-text $projectName
        get-button Finish | click
    }

    get-view "Projects list" | get-tree | get-item -path $projectName | get-property caption | equals $projectName
        | verify-true
}
------=_.ecl.context-718f04b4-ed39-33e3-af62-0995e4561998--
```

Test case itself:

```
--- RCPTT testcase ---
Format-Version: 1.0
Contexts: _N9ok0BEVEeqDjsfnLlxoAg
Element-Name: CreateProject
Element-Type: testcase
Element-Version: 3.0
External-Reference: 
Id: _MVZ5QBBFEeqrQZijmLKSfA
Runtime-Version: 2.4.3.201909171500
Save-Time: 11/28/19 1:57 PM
Testcase-Type: ecl

------=_.content-0a7243a0-75d3-3d5f-9791-539de0e5b7ac
Content-Type: text/ecl
Entry-Name: .content

get-eclipse-window | maximize
createNewProject "TEST_PROJECT"

------=_.content-0a7243a0-75d3-3d5f-9791-539de0e5b7ac--
```

When I execute the maven build, the test gets run, the tested application deploys successfully but it ends up with the following error:

```
[INFO] Fail 1 (1) processed. 1 failed. spent: 0:01, 0:00 mins remaining. CreateProject. time: 784ms  Cause: Scriptlet CreateNewProject not found
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the future generations, I got it working.
What helped for me:

- Updated maven plugin to the exact version of RCPTT IDE where I created the project (2.4.3 in my case)
- Deleted and re-created the whole project. I believe the problem was missing `rcptt.properties` file, but I'm not certain.